# Keep Save button when there is an Error on saving with Angular Xeditable

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I'm using [**Angular Xeditable api**](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-table). Could you tell me how to keep `Save` button when there is an error.Here I'm not using inbuilt input controls of x editable. I'm using `hyper link`.When user clicks, it shows the popup and so on.That functionality is working fine.I just need to keep that row on `edit` mode when there is an error.Then user can enter data without pressing `Edit` button again.Thanks.

Here is the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sampath_lokuge/NfPcH/14779/)

**Html**

```
<td>
  <a href="" ng-click="vm.note(user,rowform)">Note</a>
</td>
```

**js**

```
 $scope.saveUser = function(data, id) {
     alert('Error');
     return;
  };
```

**Note :** Please don't consider about the hyper link's functionality on the above fiddle.Just a demo.My key requirement is keep the `Save` button when there is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not super familiar with x-editable, but there is sort of built in error handler. I'll leave it to the documentation to explain it in detail, but returning a string from the onbeforesave function will make x-editable interpret the function as an error and keep the form open. Try this, should achieve what you are looking for!

```
$scope.saveUser = function(data, id) {
  var error = true;
  if (error) {
    return "Something went wrong."
  } else {
    angular.extend(data, {id: id});
    return $http.post('/saveUser', data);
  }
};
```

Comment: `angular.min.js:63 TypeError: Cannot read property '$show' of undefined`

Comment: You are right, didn't check that my solution was actually valid. I will update answer above and see how that works for you.